# Altering .htaccess with PHP - removing a rewrite rule

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, alter

I am using PHP to remove/add static pages once a page has been deleted, I want to be able to remove it from the .htaccess, however I've tried this, but it throws an error:

> **Warning**:  preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '' in ...

The code:

```
$page_name = $row['page_name']; // Example:  help
preg_replace('/RewriteRule ' . preg_quote('^' . $page_name . '/?$ page.php?mode=') . '.*/i', '', $htaccess);
```

This is an example of what it should fully remove:

```
RewriteRule ^help/?$ page.php?mode=help
```

Comment: You want to make 100% sure this script is VERY secure. Allowing PHP to modify the `.htaccess` based on any user input could result in *anything* ending up in there if you're not careful I know this bit just removes stuff but presumably it's added elsewhere? Please make sure there's no way it can be abused. At the very least, make sure it's only characters you expect, limited max length, etc...

Comment: The script is only to be inputted by administrators when making custom static pages, not anonymous users.

Comment: If that's the case and you know that a) all admins can be trusted and that b) your authentication/verification/authorisation mechanism is bullet-proof then I agree it's not a risk. I'd still be tempted to try and find an alternative though if feasibly possible - But that's just 1 man's opinion :)

Comment: There is only 2 administrators allowing to be able to access the administration panel. The script will only allow to add a simple name for a new static page, e.g. `feedback` - disallowing symbols, etc, so security is not the case here, it's the problem I need to get fixed. But thanks for your comment :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the expression delimiter by passing it to [`preg_quote`](http://www.php.net/preg_quote) as the second argument.

```
preg_replace('/RewriteRule ' . preg_quote('^' . $page_name . '/?$ page.php?mode=', '/') . '.*/i', '', $htaccess);
```

Or else your / won't be escaped. As stated in the documentation *"the special regular expression characters are: . \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -"*

Answer (score 0):

USe like this

preg_replace ( "~~msi", "pattern to replace").
Also - good practive is analise by line's not - change in all text a time!!!

so

foreach ( file(.htaccess) as $line)
{

and replace in each line,
}

than output all, store copy of old .htaccess ...

,Arsen

Comment: Sorry. I can't understand what you're saying. Could you clarify a bit more.